# FileDialogue - Apparently it doesn't work?

Tags: c#, mp3

I am currently trying to make my mp3 player for a project.

I have written this code by following a guide:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    
        string[] files, path;
        [STAThread]  
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
                path = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = path[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

And heres a screen of my form:
[image]

For some reason when I click the OPEN button, nothing happens. First when I used this code I got an error about "Form1_load", but since I wasn't using this, I just deleted the error line and then there was no errors found.

I am very clueless, so anyone with ANY idea what is wrong?

I followed this guide completely: 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ea152/mp3-media-player-in-C-Sharp-4-0/

Thanks

Comment: paste your code for "open Files" button

Comment: @andy "OPEN FILES" might have an ID of `button1`

Comment: Did you assign the Click event to your button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure that you have assigned click event for your button for that just double click on your button from design window if it redirects you to the buttonclick method then everything is fine and if it does not then assign it first. For that

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Click += button1_Click;
        }
```

And

Why do you require [STAThread]  here? I mean just remove the attribute and try again because [STAThread] is used for below reson:-

> The STAThreadAttribute marks a thread to use the Single-Threaded COM
>   Apartment if COM is needed. By default, .NET won't initialize COM at
>   all. It's only when COM is needed, like when a COM object or COM
>   Control is created or when drag 'n' drop is needed, that COM is
>   initialized. When that happens, .NET calls the underlying
>   CoInitializeEx function, which takes a flag indicating whether to join
>   the thread to a multi-threaded or single-threaded apartment.

For more information :-

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/04/07/406341.aspx

Comment: This worked perfectly! No I got another issue, I can select my mp3 files, but I can't play it?